# using an array as a reference is deprecated in perl

Tags: perl

Getting below Error: using an array as a reference is deprecated in perl script at line

Please Suggest, What is wrong in below code.

```
$sqlsyntax="exec Stored_Procedure,\@ErroeCode='$ErrMsg`"; 
@ret = $dbh->nsql ($sqlsyntax,"ARRAY");

my($EntityId,
$MaturutyDate);
my($size,$index,$count);
$size=scalar @ret;
$index=0;
$EntityId=@ret->[$index][0];
$MaturutyDate=@ret->[$index][9];
```

This perl is working fine in Solaris but when same is migrated to Linux environment, it is giving this error.

Getting below Error: using an array as a reference is deprecated in perl script at line

During Compilation it is giving this error, Want to fix this in Linux environment.

Comment: What is `@ret->[$index]` supposed to do?

Comment: @ret contains the result set in array

Comment: OK. And then what? To get an element from an array you should use `@ret[$index]`. If `$ret` was an array _reference_ you should use `$ret->[$index]`. The error message seems pretty clear; with what, exactly, do you need help?

Comment: If `@ret` is an array you maybe meant `$ret[$index]->[0]`? Or is `$ret` an array ref? Then maybe `$ret->[$index]->[0]`?

Comment: $sqlsyntax="exec Stored_Procedure,\@ErroeCode='$ErrMsg`"; 
@ret = $dbh->nsql ($sqlsyntax,"ARRAY");

Comment: @Soujain Please read [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Soujain Please don’t just dump code in comments. [Edit] the question to include all relevant code.

Comment: $EntityId=@ret->[$index][0];
$MaturutyDate=@ret->[$index][9];
As per above lines, It try to form something like below

$EntityId=@ret->[0][0];
$MaturutyDate=@ret->[0][9];

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you're getting this code from, but it uses a very old version of Perl syntax that you shouldn't have been using for a very long time. [**Update:** As ikegami points out in a comment below, this isn't very old Perl syntax - it's syntax that only worked because of a bug in Perl and which shouldn't have ever been used.]

```
@ret->[$index][0]
```

This code uses the fact that an array can (in certain circumstances) be used as an array reference. You should not do this, as there are other (simpler) ways to do the same thing. This syntax is, as you see, deprecated.

Your code should be written as `$ret[$index][0]`. If you change it to be like this, then the warnings will go away.

**Update:**

> This perl is working fine in Solaris but when same is migrated to Linux environment, it is giving this error.

I imagine that's because your Solaris system is running a far older version of Perl. What do you get from running `perl -v` on both of your systems?

Comment: Yes the code is from legacy system $ret[$index][0] is also not working , We tried with $ret[$index].[0] it doesn't have any compilation error but still not working

Comment: @Soujain: "Also not working" isn't a very helpful error report. Please explain exactly what happens. What unexpected behaviour do you see? Do you get the wrong answer? Is there an error message? Does your computer explode?

Comment: @Soujain: *"We tried with `$ret[$index].[0]`"* Trying random syntax is not the mark of a careful programmer :-)

Comment: Re "*it uses a very old version of Perl syntax*", This was never acceptable syntax. It just happened to work even though it shouldn't. A bug in Perl (arrays in scalar context are suppose to return the number of element within) made it so a bug in the user's program (`->` that shouldn't be there) didn't matter.